# DocToPdfConverter omitting Page/NumPages fields

Tags: c#, syncfusion

In our application we have a couple document exports which are generated by reading a Word document, replacing a number of placeholders and then either return the modified word document directly or converting it to PDF using Syncfusion DocIO and their `DocToPdfConverter` and return that.
So far so good.

The problem is that in the generated PDF instead of page numbers there is only blank text.

e.g. if the word document contains

> [`Field:Page` / `Field:NumPages`] (i.e. [5 / 7])

the generated PDF will instead contain

> [ / ]

The conversion code looks like this (`bytes` is the previously generated word document, which still contains the Page/Numpages fields):

```
private string ReturnPdf(string fileName, byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var wordStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        var wordDoc = new WordDocument(wordStream);

        var converter = new DocToPDFConverter();
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = converter.ConvertToPDF(wordDoc);

        // return directly in http response instead of uploading to blob storage and returning link for one-time usage
        pdfDoc.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetFileName(fileName), ".pdf"), HttpContext.Current.Response, HttpReadType.Save);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Am I missing something obvious or is this actually a bug in the converter, and if it is indeed a bug, are there any known workarounds or good alternatives (preferrably free, but not necessarily so)?

I also tried adding the following before the conversion, to no avail:

```
wordDoc.UpdateDocumentFields();
wordDoc.UpdateWordCount();
wordDoc.UpdateWordCount(performlayout: true);
wordDoc.UpdateTableOfContents();
```

**EDIT**

By some playing around I found out that one possible workaround seems to be to edit the generated .docx file in Word before converting it. Unfortunately, that's not an option for various reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now use the [Winnovative Word To PDF Converter for .NET](http://www.winnovative-software.com/word-to-pdf-converter.aspx), which does exactly what we want not only in this case but also in a couple other cases where the Syncfusion converter screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect mentioned Page field and NumPage field was missing issue may be raised due to the below codes.

```
    wordDoc.UpdateDocumentFields();
    wordDoc.UpdateWordCount();
    wordDoc.UpdateTableOfContents();
```

So kindly remove above codes and check whether the issue resolved or not. If you are still facing issue, then you can contact our support team at support@syncfusion.com to resolve the issue.

Comment: These lines were actually an attempt to solve the issue. The original code didn't contain them. I'll update the question.

Comment: These may be bug in the control. If you want to resolve this issue please contact support@syncfusion.com